# Buildozer error with threading or Signal Exception in Kivy

Tags: kivy, kivymd, buildozer, python-for-android

I'm trying to build the most basic Hello World kivy apk with buildozer and it keeps failing to build. I've tried on two different machines running Solus with Python 3.10.4 and I'm sure I have all the dependencies, I keep getting the same error:

```
[DEBUG]:   -> running rm -rf /home/solus/testapp/helloworld/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/android-sdl2/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/android
[DEBUG]:   -> running cp -a /home/solus/testapp/helloworld/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/android/src /home/solus/testapp/helloworld/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/android-sdl2/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/android
Exception in thread background thread for pid 54952:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 1009, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/threading.py", line 946, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/home/solus/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 1683, in wrap
    fn(*rgs, **kwargs)
  File "/home/solus/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 2662, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/solus/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 2349, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/solus/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 905, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.SignalException_SIGSEGV: 

  RAN: /bin/cp -a /home/solus/testapp/helloworld/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/android/src /home/solus/testapp/helloworld/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/android-sdl2/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/android

  STDOUT:


  STDERR:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 196, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/runpy.py", line 86, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/home/solus/testapp/helloworld/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1294, in <module>
    main()
  File "/home/solus/testapp/helloworld/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/home/solus/testapp/helloworld/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 728, in __init__
    getattr(self, command)(args)
  File "/home/solus/testapp/helloworld/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 151, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/home/solus/testapp/helloworld/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 210, in build_dist_from_args
    build_recipes(build_order, python_modules, ctx,
  File "/home/solus/testapp/helloworld/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 582, in build_recipes
    recipe.prepare_build_dir(arch.arch)
  File "/home/solus/testapp/helloworld/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipe.py", line 753, in prepare_build_dir
    shprint(sh.cp, '-a', join(self.get_recipe_dir(), self.src_filename),
  File "/home/solus/testapp/helloworld/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 167, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/home/solus/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 953, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/home/solus/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 879, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/home/solus/env/lib/python3.10/site-packages/sh.py", line 905, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.SignalException_SIGSEGV: 

  RAN: /bin/cp -a /home/solus/testapp/helloworld/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/android/src /home/solus/testapp/helloworld/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/android-sdl2/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/android

  STDOUT:


  STDERR:

# Command failed: /home/solus/env/bin/python -m pythonforandroid.toolchain create --dist_name=myapp --bootstrap=sdl2 --requirements=python3,kivy --arch arm64-v8a --arch armeabi-v7a --copy-libs --color=always --storage-dir="/home/solus/testapp/helloworld/.buildozer/android/platform/build-arm64-v8a_armeabi-v7a" --ndk-api=21 --ignore-setup-py --debug
# ENVIRONMENT:
#     SHELL = '/bin/bash'
#     SESSION_MANAGER = 'local/lenovo710s:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/1022,unix/lenovo710s:/tmp/.ICE-unix/1022'
#     WINDOWID = '75497479'
#     COLORTERM = 'truecolor'
#     XDG_CONFIG_DIRS = '/usr/share/xdg:/etc/xdg:/usr/share'
#     XDG_SESSION_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0'
#     GNOME_KEYRING_CONTROL = '/home/solus/.cache/keyring-2DHCO1'
#     HISTSIZE = '5000'
#     LANGUAGE = ''
#     SSH_AUTH_SOCK = '/tmp/ssh-XXXXXXkYS6ec/agent.939'
#     SHELL_SESSION_ID = '736e5be83e8f41ccb3bf3b8c37bddf9d'
#     DESKTOP_SESSION = 'plasma'
#     SSH_AGENT_PID = '940'
#     GTK_RC_FILES = '/etc/gtk/gtkrc:/home/solus/.gtkrc:/home/solus/.config/gtkrc'
#     XCURSOR_SIZE = '24'
#     GTK_MODULES = ':appmenu-gtk-module:appmenu-gtk-module:appmenu-gtk-module'
#     XDG_SEAT = 'seat0'
#     PWD = '/home/solus/testapp/helloworld'
#     XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP = 'plasma'
#     LOGNAME = 'solus'
#     XDG_SESSION_TYPE = 'x11'
#     SYSTEMD_EXEC_PID = '892'
#     XAUTHORITY = '/home/solus/.Xauthority'
#     XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR = '/var/lib/lightdm-data/solus'
#     GDM_LANG = 'en_IE.utf8'
#     GTK2_RC_FILES = '/etc/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:/home/solus/.gtkrc-2.0:/home/solus/.config/gtkrc-2.0'
#     HOME = '/home/solus'
#     SSH_ASKPASS = '/usr/bin/ksshaskpass'
#     LANG = 'en_IE.utf8'
#     XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = 'KDE'
#     KONSOLE_DBUS_SERVICE = ':1.77'
#     VIRTUAL_ENV = '/home/solus/env'
#     KONSOLE_DBUS_SESSION = '/Sessions/1'
#     PROFILEHOME = ''
#     XDG_SEAT_PATH = '/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0'
#     KONSOLE_VERSION = '220401'
#     KDE_SESSION_UID = '1000'
#     XDG_SESSION_CLASS = 'user'
#     TERM = 'xterm-256color'
#     USER = 'solus'
#     COLORFGBG = '15;0'
#     KDE_SESSION_VERSION = '5'
#     PAM_KWALLET5_LOGIN = '/tmp/kwallet5_solus.socket'
#     DISPLAY = ':0'
#     SHLVL = '1'
#     INPUTRC = '/etc/inputrc'
#     XDG_VTNR = '7'
#     XDG_SESSION_ID = '1'
#     VIRTUAL_ENV_PROMPT = '(env) '
#     LD_LIBRARY_PATH = ':/usr/local/lib'
#     XDG_RUNTIME_DIR = '/run/user/1000'
#     PS1 = ('(env) \\[\\033[38;5;081m\\]\\u\\[\\033[38;5;245m\\]@\\[\\033[38;5;206m\\]\\H '
 '\\[\\033[38;5;245m\\]\\w \\[\\033[38;5;081m\\]$ \\[\\e[0m\\]')
#     QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR = '0'
#     XCURSOR_THEME = 'breeze_cursors'
#     XDG_DATA_DIRS = '/home/solus/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop'
#     KDE_FULL_SESSION = 'true'
#     PATH = '/home/solus/.buildozer/android/platform/apache-ant-1.9.4/bin:/home/solus/env/bin:/home/solus/.local/bin:/home/solus/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/snap/bin'
#     HISTIGNORE = '&:[bf]g:exit'
#     GDMSESSION = 'plasma'
#     HISTFILESIZE = '5000'
#     DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS = 'unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus'
#     KDE_APPLICATIONS_AS_SCOPE = '1'
#     OLDPWD = '/home/solus/Dropbox/Stuff/HeroQuest/AHQ'
#     KONSOLE_DBUS_WINDOW = '/Windows/1'
#     _ = '/home/solus/env/bin/buildozer'
#     PACKAGES_PATH = '/home/solus/.buildozer/android/packages'
#     ANDROIDSDK = '/home/solus/.buildozer/android/platform/android-sdk'
#     ANDROIDNDK = '/home/solus/.buildozer/android/platform/android-ndk-r19c'
#     ANDROIDAPI = '27'
#     ANDROIDMINAPI = '21'
# 
# Buildozer failed to execute the last command
# The error might be hidden in the log above this error
# Please read the full log, and search for it before
# raising an issue with buildozer itself.
# In case of a bug report, please add a full log with log_level = 2
```

It seems to be a threading issue? I've tried more recent NDKs but get the same error. I'd appreciate any guidance.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I think solved it, I was using an older tutorial for kivy that didn't have an `if __name__ in main` in it, it still doesn't compile as now it can't install Cython even though Cython is installed in the virtual environment but that's a different problem.

Been wrestling with this for days now and as soon as I post it I solve it....